# How can I get an ID of an article using the regex for following type of URLs

Tags: php, regex

```
$string1 = "/8-a-plastic-surgery-timeline-and-how-he-would-have-looked-like-without/70/1";
$string2 = "/48/88-mindbending-pictures-that-will-make-you-question-what-you-see/12";
$string3 = "/90-the-sleeping-position-of-women-reveal-a-lot-about-them/77";
```

> From $string1, I want **70**
>
> From $string2, I want **48**
>
> From $string3, I want **77**

I have tried the following code:

```
preg_match("/(\/([0-9]+)\/*)([^\-]$)/", $string2, $matches);
```

But it is not giving me an ID of an article for all strings, I'm very close to it, but not able to get the perfect one.

Please help me out with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get these strings from a URL?

Comment: yes, I just need an article ID, I'm already having these strings

Comment: the above urls don't have a unified structure. Why an ID is placed to the end in one case and at start of the string in other case?

Comment: Hi RomanPerekhrest, I will be having these three type of Strings from URL, and from these three types of URLS, from TYPE 1, I need last second number as you can see, its **70**, from TYPE 2, I want first number as you can see, its **48** and from TYPE 3, I want the number at last which is **77**

Comment: And how do the script know which url is which?

Comment: Something like: preg_match_all("/(((\d+))\/\d+$|\/\d+\/\d+|\/(\d+)$)/", $input_lines, $output_array); ? http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fTc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with regex. Just need to make it correct.

```
preg_match("/(\d+)\/\d+$|\/(\d+)\/\d+|\/(\d+)$/", $str, $output);
```

Demo:
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fTe

Comment: **if** we **assume** the logic is "The id is the **first** url part that is **just** a number." (which i stated on my answer) then your regex fails: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fTf

Comment: @Sharky that link you made up is not part of the scope. You made a mix of two types of urls

Comment: yes, it is an assumption, (it seems to be the real case though). that's why i **bolded** the "if" and the "assume" in my previous comment

Comment: @Sharky and with the same **bold** I can there are gaps in your method too. For example `/normal-and-what-s-not/142-11` will return -1

Comment: @Sharky then maybe you can explain your assumption? Becuase I have not seen anything that makes your assumption correct or even what it means.

Comment: My assumption is "The id is the first url part that is just a number." and op's comment "Great worked perfectly for all URLS I want :)". By "first url part" i mean a part is something between "/". Your example "/normal-and-what-s-not/142-11" is not a valid url based on this assumption, as "142-11" is not just a number, it has a dash also. furthermore on OPS urls: string1 has text/ID/number (which i guess is revision (hint:wordpress)) string 2 has: ID/text/number string 3 has text/ID

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rudimentary solution.

Regex:`(?<=\/)(\d+?)(?=\/)|(?<=[A-z]{4}\/)(\d+)`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rV5eW7/1)

It would help if there was some uniformity in the three links, but if you need just a stopgap solution, this should be sufficient for now.

Comment: Hi @Anshul Rai, Thank you, I'm checking into it :)

Comment: Can you also please help me out with this /normal-and-what-s-not/142. Need **142** from this, It is not matching for this URL. And yes ofcourse I will mark it Correct Solution. Thank you

Comment: `(?<=[A-z]{4}\/)(\d+)` are you matching the word `them` in the link with the A-z?

Comment: Just update the regex to `(?<=\/)(\d+?)(?=\/)|(?<=[A-z]{4}\/)(\d+)|(?<=[A-z]{3}\/)(\d{3})`. The `\d{3}` makes sure 12 isn't matched from link 2.

Comment: @Andreas No, it's a lookbehind, it just checks for a 4 letter word, doesn't match it.

Comment: @AnshulRai Great thanks, You are expert in Regex :) Many Thanks

Comment: But if it's not a four letter word in the link? You can't make a regex that relies on a four letter word in a link in my opinion.

Comment: @AnshulRai, a small help please if you can :). It is not showing match for this string **/6-secret-signs-of-ovarian-cancer-that-you-should-be-aware-of/79** . It would be great if you can help me with that. Thank you :)

Comment: @Siddharth that's where the problem lies..what you want to extract from string is inconsistent..in first and third string you want to extract second number while in second you are extracting 1st number

Comment: @Siddharth that is what I wrote in the comment above he relies on a four letter word as the last one before the number which is bad to say the least. I will post a answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the regex on the other answer will handle other cases also.

I *guess* the logic on the ID in the urls you provided is:

"The id is the **first** url part that is **just** a number."

With that in mind you can use this function:

```
// returns -1 if no id is found
function getID($str)
{
    $arr = explode("/",$str);

    foreach($arr as $element)
    {
        if(!empty($element) && ((string)intval($element)==$element))
        {
            return $element;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

see it in action here : https://3v4l.org/rcTl6

it outputs the desired result:

```
70
48
77
142
```

p.s. and also, no regex is used. so [no extra problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) :D

Comment: Thank you very much, will try this solution too, Seems this one would be a better.

Comment: Great worked perfectly for all URLS I want :). Thanks

Comment: @Siddharth  ha! i knew that would work for other urls also :D :D i ve done a lot of url scrapping myself :D :D happy coding!